# Difficulty with the acronym package

Tags: document-classes, acronyms

Having a problem with the package acronym and the class file that my school provides.  Not sure how to provide a MWE since I think the issue is tied up with the custom class file the university provides.  What I know is that the dissertation shell they provide contains this line

```
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}  % facilitates the use of acronyms
```

When I compile my document I get an error:

> pdflatex> ! LaTeX Error: \bflabel undefined.

If I comment out that line about using the acronym package it compiles fine...but I don't get an acronym list.

Digging into the class file, I find

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@AFITdraft\singlespace\else\afit@doublespace\fi
  % adjust the acronym package's list format to conform to the AFIT style guide
  \@ifpackageloaded{acronym}{%
    \newcommand\afit@acronymwidth{Acronym}
    \renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1\hfill}}%
    \newlength\afit@acronymlabelsep
    \settowidth\afit@acronymlabelsep{\qquad}%
    \renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]{%
      \ifAC@nolist\else
        \newwrite\aftfile
        \immediate\openout\aftfile=\jobname.aft%
        \immediate\write\aftfile{\string\renewcommand\string\afit@acronymwidth{#1}}%
        \immediate\closeout\aftfile
        \raggedright\begin{list}{}{%
          \singlespace
          \setlength{\topsep}{\afit@fracskip}%
          \setlength{\itemsep}{\afit@fracskip}%
          \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
          \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
          \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}%
          \setlength{\labelsep}{\afit@acronymlabelsep}%
          \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
          \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
          \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\bflabel}%
        }%
      \fi%
```

There are two references to \bflabel in that block, and those are the only two in the whole class file.

What I think may be going on is that the acronym package has been updated, without maintaining backward compatibility, and the bflabel key is no more?  Maybe?

The kicker is that the school doesn't officially support the LaTeX class...they just put out the style guide.  The class file has been developed by students over the years, and is currently maintained by no one.

So, any suggestions on how to proceed?

Okay, significant additions to the original question:

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/bK7W9PPU) a not-quite-minimal working example.  I've taken the shell provided by the school and just commented out a lot of stuff on the off chance there are any important interactions that might be apparent...

[Here](http://pastebin.com/7C3UXbn2) is the class file the school provides.

And [here](http://pastebin.com/EJRGay9C) is the style file that the class file needs.

And finally, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tgRsFIYAadMWJEVVNULUl1MGs/view?usp=sharing) is the .pdf with the school logo that the class file refers to.

As is, this compiles and produces a document shell.  If you uncomment the lines

```
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}  % facilitates the use of acronyms
\usepackage{acronym}  % facilitates the use of acronyms
```

Then you get the

> \bflabel undefined

error.

If you go into the class file and change

```
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1\hfill}}%
```

to read

```
\newcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1\hfill}}%
```

as was suggested, then it will once again compile.  But then if you go back to the (not quite)MWE and uncomment this block

```
\listofacronyms{
\begin{acronym}[JCAAMP]
  \acro{AFMC}{Air Force Materiel Command}
    \acro{BAA}{Broad Area Announcement}
    \acro{CDF}{Cumulative Distribution Function}
    \acro{DP}{Development Planning}
    \acro{FTE}{Full Time Equivalent}
    \acro{FY}{Fiscal Year}
    \acro{HQ}{Headquarters}
    \acro{IED}{Improvised Explosive Device}
    \acro{JCAAMP}{Joint IED Defeat Capability Approval and Acquisition Management Process}
    \acro{JIEDDO}{Joint IED Defeat Organization}
    \acro{LP}{Linear Program}
    \acro{NPV}{Net Present Value}
    \acro{PMJ}{Professional Military Judgment}
  \acro{RD}{Research and Development}
\end{acronym}
}
```

which actually tries to use the acronym package, then when you compile you get multiple errors.

This seems like a real mess to me....I appreciate folks even reading this far.

Comment: Change thr `\renewcommand{\bflabel}` to `\newcommand` and see what happens, it can also point you in the right direction. Also give us the name of the class if available.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the class file and post a minimal working example so we can reproduce the problems?

Comment: Looking at the [acronym CTAN Package documentation](http://ctan.sciserv.eu/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf) suggests that there is no command `\bflabel`present in the current version of acronym. As @YiannisLazarides suggested, try changing the `\renewcommand{\bflabel}` to `\newcommand` and maybe update your question afterwards.

Comment: Changing the `\renewcommand` to `\newcommand` allows it to compile without error IF I don't actually try to use the acronym package's functionality.  As soon as I try to add an acronym environment and use the `\ac{}` command in the text it errors out.  I'm at work right now and our lovely firewall prevents logging into stackexchange....I'm typing on a phone right now so apologies if I get the markdown wrong.  I'll try to cobble together an MWE and post the class file to pastebin this evening.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, big additions to the OP with a sort of MWE and links to the required class and style files.

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `\begin{acronym} \acro... \end{acronym}`? Why does the `acronym` environment have an optional argument? And what is the `\listofacronyms` around it doing? And don't load `acronym` twice: load it once with or without `printonlyused`, as you wish.

Comment: The documentation to the acronym package says that when you begin the acronym environment, you can pass the optional argument that corresponds to the longest acronym in your list...it helps with setting column widths or some such.  As for the `\listofacronyms`, I'm following the dissertation shell there...that was the way it was provided to me.  And as for loading it twice, that was my bad...the plain one should have been the only one loaded...there's nothing in the list that isn't used in the actual document.  It makes no difference to the errors that come up though.

Comment: I didn't see `\listofaronyms` anywhere in the acronym documentation, so I went and looked in the class file and it shows up as `\newcommand\listofacronyms[1]{%
      \IfFileExists{\jobname.aft}{\makeatletter\input{\jobname.aft}\makeatother}{}%
      \newlength\afit@acronymleftmargin
      \settowidth\afit@acronymleftmargin{\afit@acronymwidth}%
      \addtolength\afit@acronymleftmargin{\afit@acronymlabelsep}%
      \addlistof{Acronyms}{\makebox[\afit@acronymleftmargin][l]{Acronym}Definition}{#1}%
    }`